# Populating an array with values in a table based on the class

Tags: html, arrays, class, each

I have a list of names in a table and all the names are given the same class using html. How do I populate an array with all the names in the list? Further, how do I print out that array? Can this be done with a .each function?

Comment: Please post the code you're tried by adding a complete example to your question.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or plain old javascript? Also, we need to know a bit more about the structure of your table if you expect any help... i.e. show us what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an HTML structure similar to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Jim</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

The following javascript (vanilla js) will retrieve your desired DOM nodes and place the values into an array:

```
//create our names array
var namesArray = [];

//fetch our names data when the DOM is fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //fetch all elements in DOM with 'name' class
    var nameElements = document.getElementsByClassName('name');

    //get the text contents of each DOM element in the nameElements array and assign it into the namesArray
    for (i = 0; i < nameElements.length; i++) {
        namesArray.push(nameElements[i].innerHTML);
    }

    //do something with the names array
    console.log(namesArray);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/9fjxzw59/)**

Comment: Just so you are aware - The jquery method (as seen in the other answers) would be a better way to approach this problem. Jquery is supported by more browser versions and is therefore more reliable. The addEventListener method is not supported by IE versions lower than 9, which some people still use

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need jquery .each

Look here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

It would be something like this

```
var array = [];
$(".class").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you build the array:

```
var myArray = [];

$(".myclass").each(function() {
    myArray[myArray.length] = $(this).text();
});
```

This is how you print the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]); //prints to the console
}
```